# Simple vs Complex: are there better (more scientific) terms?

Tags: measure-expressions

For instance:

Speed is a complex (?) measure: it is a combination of simple (?) measures (or concepts), i.e. time and distance.

Energy is treated as a complex (?) concept in physics: it is a combination of simple (?) or elementary (?) entities, i.e. time, distance, and mass.

Are there better words for simple (or **elementary**) and **complex**? ... Compound? ...

Comment: _Energy_ is itself a _single property_ of objects. It is _not_ a combination of anything, nor is it ever treated as such in physics. Neither is _speed_ a combination of anything. _Velocity_ specifies the speed and direction of motion of an object, so maybe that is what you mean. _Time_ in physics means only _that which is measured by a clock,_ and it is never "combined" with anything else. All of your premises are false! A better understanding of physics might lead you to an answer without assistance.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Yeah, okay, you don't know much, do you.

Comment: "Does gravity turn itself off when it has nothing to work on?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this document](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html), the unit system that we use (SI, or Systeme Internationale) defines seven **base** units- metres, kilograms seconds, amperes, kelvin, moles and candela. All others are considered to be **derived** units.